# Exit a scrip if condition

Tags: python-3.x, exit

I want to exit my script (the whole program) if a certain list is empty(which it is). I have tried sys.exit() and os.exit() but it isn't working:

```
TempPos = []
for child in root.iter():
 if child.tag == 'InArea':
     TempFrom = child.get('v')
 if child.tag == 'Qty':
     TempQty.append(int(child.get('v')))

if len(TempQty) == 0:
 os._exit(0)

if 'FR' in TempFrom:
 From = 'FR'
```

When using os.exit:

I keep getting an error message on the line after the exit:

"if 'FR' in TempFrom:
NameError: name 'TempFrom' is not defined"

When using sys.exit:

I am getting this error message:

UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Why doesn't it just exit the script?

ANSWER: use just exit()

From @iDrwish comment

Comment: "Why doesn't it just exit the script?" - perhaps the list isn't empty?

Comment: it is. I have checked by printing the length which is 0.

Comment: Have you tried just using `exit()`?

Comment: That actually seems to work